# How to change Monolog's default date timezone globally in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog

I Am using Monolog in Symfony 2 to do logging, Monolog uses default timezone set in `php.ini` and fallbacks to UTC.

There is no a configuration parameter that determines the timezone for Monolog.

One way to change the used timezone is to use `\Monolog\Logger::setTimezone()`, but I don't want to iterate at everytime I use logging and make sure I used the `\Monolog\Logger::setTimezone()`.

As timezone is used globally for all logger instances If I somehow set timezone in some sort of an init function before it is used? My problem is Symfony handles Monolog's instantiation and injection, is there is a way where I can tell Symfony to use setTimezone() after instantiating the logger instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        Logger::setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    }
}
```